# Simpler notation for enumerated lists

Tags: macros, enumerate

I'm creating documents with many multilevel enumerated lists and I'm looking for ways to simplyfy the notation.

Ideally I would like to write something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    Some text here
    \i first item
    \i second item

    more text

    \i third item
    \par third item continues

    \i fourth item

    \ii fifth item

    \ii sixth item
    \ii seventh item

    more text

    \ii eighth item
    \i ninth item

\end{document}
```

And I would like it to be translated to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    Some text here
    \begin{enumerate}[resume=level1]
        \item\setcounter{enumii}{0} first item
        \item\setcounter{enumii}{0} second item
    \end{enumerate}
    more text
    \begin{enumerate}[resume=level1]
        \item\setcounter{enumii}{0} third item
        \par third item continues
        \item\setcounter{enumii}{0} fourth item
        \begin{enumerate}[resume=level2]
            \item fifth item

            \item sixth item
            \item seventh item
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    more text
    \begin{enumerate}[resume=level1]
        \item[]
        \begin{enumerate}[resume=level2]
            \item eighth item
        \end{enumerate}
        \item\setcounter{enumii}{0} ninth item
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

More specifically:

- If `\i` is not preceeded by another item, then `\begin{enumerate}[resume=level1]` is added before.
- If `\i` is not followed by a paragraph not beginning with `\i` or `\ii`, then `\end{enumerate}` is added after.
- If paragraph break is marked with \par instead of two line braks, then it is included in the previous item and the list is not terminated.
- Level2 items `\ii` are preceeded or followed by `\begin{enumerate}[resume=level2]` and `\end{enumerate}` accordingly.
- If `\ii` is not preceeded by level 1 item or level 2 item, then `\begin{enumerate}[resume=level1]` and a dummy level 1 item `\item[]` are also added.
- If `\ii` should resume from the previous level 2 numbering if there has been no level 1 item inbetween.

Would it be possible with reasonable effor to define macros that would achieve this?

Comment: What's the purpose of the five `\setcounter{enumii}{0}` instructions?

Comment: `\i` is already defined, you shouldn't redefine it.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. Its three main working assumptions are (A) there are two levels of enumerated lists, (B) the strings `\i` and `\ii` occur at the start of a line, while possibly being preceded by whitespace, and (C) any lines with `\par` instructions are *not* preceded by all-blank lines. The third assumption is not (at least not explicitly) in the the OP's list of working assumptions; however, without this assumption the already-complicated code even more complicated.

The bulk of the work is performed by a Lua function called `FancyEnum`. Two utility LaTeX macros, called `\FancyEnumOn` and `\FancyEnumOff`, serve to activate and deactivate the Lua function's operation on the input stream. For sure, you should run `\FancyEnumOff` ahead of verbatim material that features the strings `\i` and `\ii`.

*Update*, after receiving more information from the OP about the purpose of the `\setcounter{enumii}{0}` directives. (Their purpose was to make sure that a "new" level-2 list -- where "new" means that there's been at least one intervening level-1 `\item` directive -- starts at 0.) The purpose is much more easily achieved by running `\begin{enumerate}[series=level2]` instead of `\begin{enumerate}[resume=level2]` whenever a new level-2 lists begins. I've updated the Lua code accordingly.

The following screenshot shows the result of the operations of the Lua function on (a slightly modified form of) the OP's suggested example on the left and the corresponding hard-coded enumerated lists on the right.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol} % to create two-column output

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode*' environment
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
-- Begin by defining 2 Boolean variables. They will be set to 'true' if
-- LaTeX is in a level-1 or level-2 enumerated environment, respectively.
local in_enumi =false
local in_enumii=false

-- The Lua function 'FancyEnum' does most of the work.
function FancyEnum ( s )  
  -- Input line starts with '\i' (possibly preceded by whitespace):
  if s:find ( "^%s-\\i " ) then
    if in_enumii==true then -- need to fall back one list level
      s = s:gsub ( "^%s-\\i " , "\\end{enumerate}\\item " )
      in_enumii=false
    elseif in_enumi==true then -- continue at level 1
      s = s:gsub ( "^%s-\\i " , "\\item " )
    else -- neither in_enumi nor in_enumii are true -- start a level-1 list
      s = s:gsub ( "^%s-\\i " , "\\begin{enumerate}[resume=level1] \\item " )
      in_enumi=true
    end
  -- Input line starts with '\ii' (possibly preceded by whitespace):
  elseif s:find ( "^%s-\\ii " ) then
    if in_enumii==true then -- continue at level 2
      s = s:gsub ( "^%s-\\ii " , "\\item " )
    elseif in_enumi==true then -- Moving from level 1 to level 2. Hence,
                -- we use '[series=level2]' rather than '[resume=level2]'
      in_enumii=true
      s = s:gsub ( "^%s-\\ii " , "\\begin{enumerate}[series=level2]\\item " )
    else -- jumping straight to level-2 list
      in_enumi=true
      in_enumii=true
      s = s:gsub ( "^%s-\\ii " , "\\begin{enumerate}[resume=level1]\\item[]" ..
                                 "\\begin{enumerate}[resume=level2]\\item " )
    end
  -- Input line is all-blank. Terminate 'enumerate' if 'in_enumi' and/or
  -- 'in_enumii' are 'true'.
  elseif s=="" then 
    if in_enumii==true then    -- terminate two 'enumerate' levels
      s = "\\end{enumerate}\\end{enumerate}" 
      in_enumii=false
      in_enumi=false
    elseif in_enumi==true then -- terminate one 'enumerate' level
      s = "\\end{enumerate}"
      in_enumi=false
    end 
  end

  -- Place 's' back on the input stream, for further processing by LaTeX.
  return s 
end -- end of Lua function
```

```lua
\end{luacode*}

%% Two LaTeX utility macros that activate and deactivate 'FancyEnum':
\newcommand\FancyEnumOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", FancyEnum, "FancyEnum")}}
\newcommand\FancyEnumOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", "FancyEnum")}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

    \FancyEnumOn % activate the Lua function 'FancyEnum'
    \verb+\FancyEnum+ on

    \i first item
    \i second item

    more text

    \i third item
    \par third item continues % note: no blank line before this line

    \i fourth item

    \ii fifth item

    \ii sixth item
    \par sixth item continues  % note: no blank line before this line

    \i  seventh item
    \ii eighth item  % note: no blank line before this line

    more text

    \ii ninth item

    \i tenth item

    \FancyEnumOff % deactivate 'FancyEnum'
    \columnbreak % optional

    \verb+\FancyEnum+ off (explicit lists)
    \begin{enumerate}[series=level1] % not [resume=level1]
    \item first item
    \item second item
    \end{enumerate}
    more text
    \begin{enumerate}[resume=level1]
    \item third item

          third item continues
    \item fourth item

    \begin{enumerate}[series=level2]
    \item fifth item

    \item sixth item

          sixth item continues
    \end{enumerate}
    \item seventh item
    \begin{enumerate}[series=level2]
    \item eighth item
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    more text
    \begin{enumerate}[resume=level1]
    \item[]
    \begin{enumerate}[resume=level2]
    \item ninth item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item tenth item
    \end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The purpose of `\setcounter{enumii}{0}` directives is to make sure that level 2 enumeration always starts at 0 if there is a level 1 item in between. In your screenshot the second level enumeration after item 9 should start at (a). I ckecked and this is what happens if I compile my example code. Of course there might be a better way to achieve that result.

Comment: @ttsc - Thanks for this explanation. I don't think that running `\setcounter{enumii}{0}` actually helps achieve your objective. (Moreover, the sample code you provided in your query doesn't actually give an example that would demonstrate this objective in action.) Let me think a bit about how your objective might be achieved in the setting used in my answer.

Comment: `\setcounter{enumii}{0}` did do the job when I tested it, but I welcome a better solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with LuaLaTeX and I'm not trying it for the first time. Apparently the directive on the first line of your code was not enough and I had to change the executable to lualatex instead of pdflatex. However, your code still does not compile. I get `./fancyenumetest.tex:55: Undefined control sequence.`. Also, I see that you have written booolean with three "o"s. Changing this did make the error message go away, but I wonder if this is intentional.

Comment: I really like the way luacode looks. It looks like a normal programmingn language that I can understand. I wasn't aware of this kind of possibility before. I wonder if it is completely compatible with the old way of writing LaTeX. We have quite a big amount of custom LaTeX code in our documents. Is it a good idea to implement one feature with luacode when other features are implemented with traditional LaTeX code?

Comment: @ttsc - The opening line. `% !TEX TS-program = lualatex`, works with some editors, e.g, TeXworks and TeXshop (but not alas not all editors out there), to switch the engine from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX. If your editor (did you state which one you use?) doesn't know what to do with the `% !TEX TS-program = lualatex` meta directive, you will have to switch the program by hand, using whatever method your editor affords. I'm afraid I have absolutely no idea how your formatting objectives might be achieved under pdfLaTeX. Hopefully, somebody else will come up with a pdfLaTeX-based solution.

Comment: @ttsc - Incidentally, my powers of divination are rubbish. If somebody tells me that there was an `Undefined control sequence` error message but won't tell me what the offending control sequence is, the odds that I'll be able to figure out what's going on are sadly nil.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you'd know it because of the line number. I just copypasted the code, so line numbers should be the same. The error is reported to be on the line that says `\end{luacode}`. I could paste the whole output here, but I'm not sure how to make make it fit in the comment. Would it help if you got the whole output? If yes, what would be the best way to send it to you?

Comment: @ttsc - Please see if the updated code works for you. (Switch from `luacode` to `luacode*` environment.)

Comment: @ttsc - Rather than run `\setcounter{enumii}{0}` each and every time a level-1 `\item` directive is encountered, just run `\begin{enumerate}[series=level2]` instead of `\begin{enumerate}[resume=level2]` when switching from a level-1 to a level-2 list. I'm updating the Lua code and the example to reflect this change.

Comment: @ttsc - You asked in an earlier comment, "I wonder if [LuaLaTeX] is completely compatible with the old way of writing LaTeX? LuaLaTeX is largely a superset of pdfLaTeX, with two very significant additions: The availability of the scripting language Lua and the ability to use system fonts (in practice mainly via the `fontspec`). Nowadays, LuaLaTeX is highly stable and almost entirely backward compatible with pdfLaTeX. The main adjustment you may have to make is to stop loading the `inputenc` and `fontenc` package; in their place, load the `fontspec` package.

Comment: It works now! One small thing: The enumerate environment should not be terminated by a blank line if the blank line is followed by another item. It should be terminated only if the next non-whitespace thing after the blank line is not an item. I do understand your code, but I didn't yet succeed in figuring out how to fix this.

Comment: @ttsc - The reason I added "working assumption (C)" is that the Lua code would become *a lot more complicated* if I had to add a general-purpose look-ahead condition to determine whether an all-blank line should or should not indicate the end of an `enumerate` environment. In practice, this mostly affects instances of  (a) `\par`-continued material within a (level-1 or level-2) item and (b) `\i` followed by `\ii`, where we need a restart of `enumii`. I suggest the following work-around: Don't leave blank lines in such. I hope this work-around is acceptable.

Comment: Actually having blank lines between items is important because it makes the code more readable. However, I figured out an easy way to do this. I added a flag tellin if the previous line was blank and the enumerate environment is closed if the line does not begin with an item and the previous line was blank. I think it would be useful to post my changes here, but how should I do that? Should I post a separate answer that has the additions to your code?

Comment: @ttsc - Please feel free to edit my posting directly.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you want to use the [easylist](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/easylist) package. It does not quite give you all of the features that you want but it is pretty close. For example, the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sharp]{easylist}% sharp => # is used for \item
\begin{document}

Some text here
\begin{easylist}[articletoc]
    # first item
    # second item

    more text

    # third item
    \par third item continues

    # fourth item

    ## fifth item

    ## sixth item
    ## seventh item

    more text

    ## eighth item
    # ninth item
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

There are many extra options that can be controlled using `\ListProperties`, such as `Hang=<n>` for setting hanging indents. The manual is very readable.

**EDIT**
The folllowing might be close enough to what you want. You can disable the counter for the first list level using

```
\ListProperties(
    Hang=true,
    Hide1=1,
    Hide2=1,
    Hide3=1,
    Hide4=1,
    Progressive*=2em,
    Style1*=\theblank,
    Indent1=0em,
)
```

As a result, the following code

```
\begin{easylist}
# Some text here
## first item
## second item

# more text

## third item
\par third item continues

## fourth item

### fifth item

### sixth item
### seventh item

# more text

### eighth item
## ninth item
\end{easylist}
```

produces

[image]

So every line has at least one `#`, corresponding to not being inside a list, whereas the lines with `##` are inside the first list (level 1), those with `###` are at level 2 and so on.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sharp]{easylist}% sharp => # is used for \item
\begin{document}

\ListProperties(
    Hang=true,
    Hide1=1, % hide counter 1 on level 1
    Hide2=1, % hide counter 1 on level 2
    Hide3=1, % hide counter 1 on level 3
    Hide4=1, % hide counter 1 on level 4
    Progressive*=2em,
    Style1*=\theblank,
    Indent1=0em,
)

\begin{easylist}
# Some text here
## first item
## second item

# more text

## third item
\par third item continues

## fourth item

### fifth item

### sixth item
### seventh item

# more text

### eighth item
## ninth item
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the features that are not provided by easylist?

Comment: @ttsc I may have missed it in the manual, but I don't think that there's an easy way to have the same list level before and after a sublist.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you give an example?

Comment: For my purpose it is important to have normal paragraph text with sections an tables between items and the normal text should not be formatted as a continuation of the list item but as a normal paragraph. Also, I also need to have pictures and tables and multiple paragraphs inside list items. Are these features available in easylist?

Comment: @ttsc For example, your "more text" lines are supposed to be at "level 0", which is outside of a list/enumerate environment, but I don't know how to break out of level 1 (i.e. inside a list) and return temporarily to level 0. To return to level 0 you can, of course, close the `easylist` environment but if you have a list item at level 1 that contains a sublist at level 2 the only way to return to level 1 is to start a new level one `\item`, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Closing easylist and opening a new one might work if it is possible to continue numbering from where it was left. I just tested it and it seems to start at one every time by default.

Comment: @ttsc You can do this using, for example, `\ListProperties(Start1=17)`. Not sure if this can be automated. I was just playing around and trying to set the first counter to be blank (so that `# text` is "level 0".. , this almost works except that  the level 1 counter contains the level 0 counter and I have not succeeded in disabling this.

Comment: @ttsc OK, I misunderstood how `Hide` works inside `\ListProperties`. I've edited my code to give give something closer to what you are asking for.